# Statistics injection for calculating the cost of a query

Tags: postgresql, table, statistics

I want to find out the cost of a query by "EXPLAIN" query in Postgres. As I know, Postgres calculate this cost by using the statistics of the table. (e.g: relpages, reltuples in pg_class or some attributes in pg_statistics)
Is it possible to inject these statistics on a dummy table to get the cost without storing the data locally on the database?

Comment: It's not likely available as is. However, if you can find the code in Postgres which does that math, you probably could replicate that with any data you have available.